# Zoom persist on next imageview

Tags: java, android

I've very annoying problem. Hope you can help me.

This part of my application is simple. When user taps NEXT or PREVIOUS button, imageview switches to previous or next image available. It works great but only if user does not use multitouch to ZOOM image. Please check images below to see what my problem is. I'm using **TouchImageView** library to zoom images.

IMAGE 1: This is image in it's normal state.

[image]

IMAGE 1 - ZOOM: User decides to use multitouch because it wants to ZOOM the image.

[image]

IMAGE 2: User taps Next button, but on the screen appears next image but it is in its ZOOMED state (from previous image).

[image]

Instead it should be like this:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to "reset" image and even if current picture is zoomed, next picture should not be zoomed?

Comment: Please check http://www.rqgg.net/topic/isuuh-how-to-reset-the-zoom-level-of-android-imageview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about [this TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/example/touch/TouchImageView.java), you could add a method that wraps the logic inside

```
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector);
```

in a method called `setScaleFactor(float scaleFactor, float focusX, floatY);`

That way, `onScale` method would look like.-

```
@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) { 
    float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
    setScaleFactor(mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

    return true;
}
```

And you could call

```
setScaleFactor(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
```

to 'reset' the scale.

**EDIT**

Assuming you're working with the `TouchImageView` implementation given on the link above, `setScaleFactor` would look like this.-

```
public void setScaleFactor(float mScaleFactor, float focusX, float focusY) {
    float origScale = saveScale;
    saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
    if (saveScale > maxScale) {
        saveScale = maxScale;
        mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
    } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
         saveScale = minScale;
         mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
    }

    if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight) {
        matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
    } else {
        matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, focusX, focusY);
    }
    fixTrans();
}
```

Comment: Okay, and what do I need to add in method "setScaleFactor"?

Comment: Just added the code snippet. Please, take it as an example as I didn't tested, but it's a start.

Comment: Okay thanks. But the problem is that "detector" variable in setScaleFactor method is not recognized because it's local to onScale method, therefore I cannot use it in my own method.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you can pass `detector.getFocusX()` and `detector.getFocusY()` to setScaleFactor as well. Updated the code in answer. Not sure if focus center would be 0.5, 0.5 or width/2, height/2, though

Comment: No problem. Thanks for helping, but now I only need to call "setScaleFactor". I should call this method when I change the image? (button press) ?

Comment: That's right, whenever you need zoom scale return to default, you'd do something like `yourImageView.setScaleFactor(1.0, 0.5, 0.5);`

Comment: It's not related to my problem but for some reason eclipse does not detect method "setScaleFactor" in my project from TouchImageView library, even if I made it public. Do you know what could be the problem? Sorry to bother you..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37345/discussion-between-ssantos-and-rootpanthera)

Comment: It worked BUT i've changed method to : setScaleFactor(0f, 0f, 0f);